# Plot phase graph from impulse response with delay adjustment

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft, phase

I'm trying to plot the phase graph of an impulse response with python, but the phase [looks rather distorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj8BX.png).

How can I add a delay to my code, so that the phase graph looks better, [like in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW40R.png)?

I know that a have to add a delay of 1024 samples / 21.333ms, but don't know how

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fs = 48000
taps = [...]
n = len(taps)//2+1
x=np.linspace(0, fs/2, n, endpoint=True)
h = np.fft.fft(taps)
plt.semilogx(X, np.angle(h[:n], deg=True))
```

Comment: Have a look at [`numpy.unwrap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html#numpy-unwrap)